# Team Foundation Server 2018 Code Commit Date

Tags: git, tfs

We are using Team Foundation Server 2018 with Git.  I am creating a report in SSRS and one of the parameters of the report is the ProjectNodeSK.  I would only like to include projects that have had code committed to them recently.  Is such data stored in the Tfs_Warehouse database or another database and if so what database and table(s) can I query for this information?

(I am aware the TFS team prefers us to use APIs and not access the databases directly. I do not intend on changing any data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may check table `[Tfs_DefaultCollection].[dbo].[tbl_GitCommitStatus]`. In this table, there is a `InternalRepositoryId` field which can be linked to table `[Tfs_DefaultCollection].[dbo].[tbl_GitRepository]`, then you can find the repo id and name.

Answer (score 0):

No. The reporting situation isn't very cohesive, although that's changing. Basically, the warehouse hasn't received updates to include new features introduced since approximately TFS 2013. That includes Git, the new build system, the new release system, etc.

Per Microsoft, the next major version of TFS will have a more robust, modern reporting solution in the form of the [Analytics service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/report/analytics/what-is-analytics?view=vsts).

Comment: The last commit has to surely be stored somewhere in SQL Server.?.?.?

Comment: @BillGreer Probably. The TFS operational store schema is undocumented and I have no particular insights into it because you should not write queries against it.

Comment: Sometimes you have to.  :)  <requirements>
Thanks